# insert Code before Build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vs-extensibility, vspackage, intellitrace

I am building a vspackage for Visual Studio 2010, and need to be able to inject code  invisibly into every function in the solution during the build process.

Currently I can use this:

```
TextDocument doc = (elemInfo.ProjectItem.Document.Object() as TextDocument);

EditPoint ep = doc.CreateEditPoint(elemInfo.StartPoint);
ep.Insert(sb.ToString());
```

which inserts the code directly into the code file for all to see. This works, but as the code only collects runtime data I never need to see it. Is there a way to inject the code during the build process without publically inserting the code like above?

I could create temporary files for all the code files in the solution, and inject the code into them, then dispose of them after the debug session ends. Would this be the best way?

When intellitrace collects data from the running executable, wouldn't it need to do something similiar to this? I assume it Injects code into each method to save variable states.

Comment: [AOP](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) FTW

Comment: lol your comment reads aop ftw bzlm, seems like incomprehensible babble at a glance XD

Answer (score 1):

PostSharp, http://www.sharpcrafters.com/
Essentially AOP as per @bzlm

Comment: I don't see how this helps, my visual studio plugin could be used on any c# project, and they not necessarily be using postsharp. The user clicks a button and then the code is injected, followed by the running of the program, and then the removal of the code at the end of the run. Preferably all this would be done invisibly which postsharp does not achieve (requires attributes). I don't think the cost is justified for this small plugin either.